# How to Play Music and Display Paragraph on Click in Android Application?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, sdk

I'm a beginner to android app development and i want to know how to perform above task.

As I'm building an Poem app which will display poem along with music of specific language to which user clicked on !!

[image]

Comment: please show what you have attempted so far and what problem you are facing with your attempt

Comment: So far i have made it's interface & now i want to add these functionality, but don't know how to proceed.

Comment: @GautamChaurasia you can google for how to play mp3 file.